# SQL Insert all records that don't exist for every value of dimension

Tags: sql, hana

I'd like to insert every id that does not yet exist for a certain yearmonth into the same table, goal can be seen below:

```
ID  YearMonth

1   201805
2   201805
1   201804
1   201803
```

Should be:

```
ID  YearMonth

    1   201805
    2   201805
    1   201804
    1   201803
    2   201803
    2   201804
```

Does anyone have any idea how this could be done using SQL?

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

I've already tried:

```
select A."ID",B."YEARMONTH" FROM "1_TEST" A FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select "YEARMONTH" from "1_TEST" GROUP BY "YEARMONTH") B
ON A."YEARMONTH" != B."YEARMONTH"
```

But this generated too many records.

DB is a HANA system.

Comment: Please add some code examples of what you have tried by now.

Comment: pls explain in full  and what u last tried.

Comment: Please tag which RDBMs this is for

Comment: I've added what I've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with: a column is called `ID` because it uniquely identifies a record in the table. As there are duplicate IDs in your table, these are obviously IDs of another table and should be named thus.

Anyway, you want all IDs you find in the table combined with all months you find in the table. That would be a cross join:

```
select ids.id, yearmonths.yearmonth
from (select distinct id from mytable) ids
cross join (select distinct yearmonth from mytable) yearmonths;
```

(Please note: I use distinct selects from your table, because you haven't shown us any other tables. If there is a parent table containing the unique IDs then I'd rather use that. Same for the YearMonths; if there is a YearMonth table, use that instead of gathering the distinct values from the combination table.)

However, you say you don't want to select these only, but insert missing records in the table.

```
insert into mytable (id, yearmonth)
  select ids.id, yearmonths.yearmonth
  from (select distinct id from mytable) ids
  cross join (select distinct yearmonth from mytable) yearmonths
  except
  select id, yearmonth from mytable;
```

In HANA you may be able to shorten this to:

```
upsert mytable
  select ids.id, yearmonths.yearmonth
  from (select distinct id from mytable) ids
  cross join (select distinct yearmonth from mytable) yearmonths;
```

This only inserts new rows, because all selected columns are part of the table's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT "ID","YEARMONTH" FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT A."ID",B."YEARMONTH" FROM "1_TEST" A, (SELECT "YEARMONTH" FROM "1_TEST" GROUP BY "YEARMONTH") B )
 WHERE ("ID","YEARMONTH") NOT IN (SELECT "ID","YEARMONTH" FROM "1_TEST")
```

Update, better version:

```
 SELECT "ID","YEARMONTH" FROM (
 SELECT A."ID",B."YEARMONTH" FROM (SELECT "ID" FROM "1_TEST" GROUP BY "ID") A, (SELECT "YEARMONTH" FROM "1_TEST" GROUP BY "YEARMONTH") B )
 WHERE ("ID","YEARMONTH") NOT IN (SELECT "ID","YEARMONTH" FROM "1_TEST")
```